# How to delete another pod when based on lifeCycle of one pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a requirement to delete all pods for `service1-deployment` when container restart happens in `service2-deployment`.

I found out that we can do it through [lifeCycle event](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/) handler `service2-deployment`.

But we can not specify `kubeclt delete pod` command here since it runs inside a pod. Is there any easy way to restart 2nd pod based on 1st Pod's lifeCycle events?

Comment: What leads to this; can you restructure your application to avoid it?  Pods can be deleted automatically for reasons outside your control (for example, the node is overcommitted on resources and your pod happens to get evicted) and having a cascading sequence of Deployment restarts seems like it will be disruptive to your application.

Comment: @DavidMaze You are absolutely right . In microservice architecture services should be independent. Recently we migrated from Monolith to Microservice . Still there is a  dependency on bootstrapping data  which we are planning to move away from . Till then we are looking for this solution to avoid writing invalid data into db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer** - as mentioned in the comments,  you should avoid this solution ([microservices should be independent](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/411082/should-microservices-be-independent/411136#411136)) until you really have no other choice.

---

You can [setup both `postStart` and `preStop` handlers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers) (for installing `kubectl` binary and for deleting the pods from deployment), but first you need to create a [proper Service Account for the pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) and [Role(Bindings)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) with permissions to delete pods:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: role-for-hook
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: service-account-for-hook
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: delete-pods-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: service-account-for-hook
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: delete-pods-role
  labels:
    # Add these permissions to the "view" default role.
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["delete","list"]
```

Then, you can use newly created Service Account + `postStart` and `preStop` handlers in pod / deployment definition - example for NGINX image. I assumed, that the label for the pods from the `Service1` is `app=service1`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service2-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: service2
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: service2
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: service-account-for-hook
      containers:
      - name: service2
        image: nginx:latest
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apt update && apt install curl && curl -L https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl"] 
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "kubectl delete pods -l app=service1"]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

Then, if the pod from `Service2` is restarted, the pods from `Service1` are also restarted.

Commands used in the `command:` could be different for you, it depends which base image you are using for your application.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this . It worked in case of pod restart . But in case of abrupt restart of container it did not work .Also i did not see any event captured for deployment / pod .

Comment: Could you please provide some example to reproduce a similar restart behaviour as yours?

Answer (score 0):

you can call `rest API of api-server` to delete pods of another deployment..

you can call your custom API after lifecycle event got executed
[something like this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#python-client)

Comment: I think it requires API server and TOKEN information . Will do some research